# lxml cssselect - specific part

Tags: python, parsing, css-selectors, lxml

I need to get the Translations section of a web page.

[image]

This is my python code:

```
import urllib.request

u = urllib.request.urlopen("https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#structure-of-the-repository")
data = u.read()

from lxml import html
information = html.document_fromstring(data)

for content in information.cssselect('ul li a'):
    print(content.text_content())
```

In the end, I'm getting also the Table of contents section, and I do not know how to filter the information.

What could be a proper way to reach this?

I have to say that I have never worked with python, my knowledge about this is limited.

Comment: first find all `ul` and use second of them to get `li a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all `ul` and then use correct one to get `li a`

I found that 6th `ul` has your data

```
for content in information.cssselect('ul')[6].cssselect('li a'):
    print(content.text_content())
```

Result

```
English
French
Chinese
Japanese
Korean
Filipino
Brazilian Portuguese
```

---

**EDIT:** The same using `xpath` needs `7` instead of `6` because it starts counting at `1` instead of `0`

```
for content in information.xpath('(//ul)[7]/li/a'):
    print(content.text_content())
```

Comment: I have learned something new with you. Your answer is clear and precise. Thanks a lot!!